# Laravel 5 eloquent: select specific column of relation

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 models: Author and Post

In my Post model, I have an author function (One To Many (Inverse)):

```
public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author', 'author_id');
    }
```

Now I want to export to Excel the following information:

id | title | author name

This is what I tried:

```
$posts = Post::with(array(
        'author' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('name');
        }))->select('id', 'title')->get();
```

What I get is an empty author's name column.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Try get('id AS Id','title AS Title','authors.name AS Name') instead of ->select('id', 'title')->get();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please try:

```
$posts = Post::with(['author' => function($query){
    $query->select(['id','name']);
}])->get(['id','title', 'author_foreign_key_in_posts_table']);
```

Having that, you'll be able to get:

```
$posts->first()->author->name;
$posts->first()->id;
$posts->first()->title;
```

You may use iteration or whatever instead of first() for export.

Answer (score 6):

Since Laravel 5.5 you can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) retrieve multiple specific columns simply by using string

```php
Post::with('author:id,name')->get()

Author::with('posts:id,author_id,title')->get()
```

> **Notice the `id` or foreign key (`author_id`) must included, or data will be null**.

Comment: Thanks, the point was the foreign key, that I missed